# How to add conditional counter to numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to replace a numpy array values with a counter, if they meet a condition.

'Arr' is a `NxM`  numpy array. I would like 'ArrCount' `(NxM)` to have values from `i=1 to i=n`, if the value in 'Arr' doesn't equal 65535. 
for large arrays, iterating over each cell takes a long time.

```
import numpy as np
ArrCount= np.empty_like(Arr)
    i = 1
    for index, x in np.ndenumerate(Arr):
        if x!= 65535:
            ArrCount[index] = i
            i += 1
```

I've also tries working with mask and Boolean arrays, but this doesn't improve the iterating  time. 
Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry it isn't clear to me exactly what you want to do. Can you supply an example input and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid for-loops at all when you use Numpy.
Here is a vectorized approach to do something like that:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10)

# boolean array, other operators also work (>=, ==, <=)
is_larger = a > 0.5

# how many elements fit the criteria?
count = np.count_nonzero(is_larger)

# create an ascending array that long
asc = np.arange(count)

# boolean indexing to assign the values to the correct places
a[is_larger] = asc

print(a)
```

Comment: Thanks This works great in a much more efficient way. i knew i needed to avoid looping just didn't know how.